# How to set the default value in a Microsoft SQL Server table to yesterday's date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in Microsoft SQL Server and it is currently set so that when a row is added, it adds the date the row was added to the column name, Date. I did this using `getdate()` as the default value for this column. The issue is that the data being put in the rows is data from the previous day. How would I set a default value so that when the row is added, instead of adding the current date to the column Date, it adds the previous day's date?

Comment: Change it from `GETDATE()` to `DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())`

Comment: handle properly the timezone. my guess is that the timezone of your client is different from the one of the server. if you alter the default you will incur in the very same issue if anyone connects from a timezione that is not server's or your's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace: `GETDATE()`

with: `DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())`

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) some info about `DATEADD` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #test (
ID INT,
myDate DATETIME CONSTRAINT DF_Date DEFAULT DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
);

INSERT INTO #test ( ID ) VALUES ( 1 );

SELECT *
FROM #test
```

If you want to add date only, without time part, use `CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)` instead.